# Increase time until destroying prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine, destroy

I am firing a ball of sticky goo. In my `onStart()` I am calling `Destroy(Goo, 5f)` which will destroy it after 5 seconds from when it was created.

However, I have an `onTriggerEnter()` that is being called when the goo hits the main character. In this case - I want to prolong the life of the goo for an extra 5 seconds.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if Unity has anything like this built in, but you could simply use your own internal timer rather than calling a delayed destroy.

```
void onStart()
{
    mDestroyTimer = 5.0f;
}

void Update()
{
    mDestroyTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (mDestroyTimer <= 0)
    {
        Destroy(Goo);
    }
}

onTriggerEnter()
{
    mDetroyTimer += 5.0f;
}
```

I'm sure it's possible to come up with a more elegant solution but this should give you good control over the lifespan of the Goo object.